# Excluding test classes for all analysis from gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I'm invoking sonar using sonar-runner plugin from gradle. I'm also using the reuse reports flag.
How can I exclude all test classes from all analyses (Checkstyle, Findbugs, Coverage)?

I'm currently using the following plugin configuration:

```
sonarRunner {
sonarProperties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "<HOST>"

    property "sonar.scm.disabled", "true"
    property "sonar.login", "<USER>"
    property "sonar.password", "<password>"

    property "sonar.sources", "src"
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/test/**/*.java"
    property "sonar.projectVersion", project.releaseDisplayName
    // these should not change anything as sonar uses the defaults set for gradle
    //property "sonar.tests", "test"
}
```

My source sets are as follows:

```
sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
        srcDir 'src-gen'
    }
}
test {
    java { srcDir 'test' }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Anything you've tried so far? How are you currently configuring sourcesets? Show your plugin configuration.

Comment: My Configuration is like this:

sonarRunner {
 sonarProperties {
  property "sonar.host.url", "<HOST>"
  
  property "sonar.scm.disabled", "true"
  property "sonar.login", "<USER>"
  property "sonar.password", "<password>"

  property "sonar.sources", "src"
  property "sonar.exclusions", "**/test/**/*.java"
  property "sonar.projectVersion", project.releaseDisplayName
  // these should not change anything as sonar uses the defaults set for gradle
  //property "sonar.tests", "test"
 }
}

Comment: how are your sourcesets setup?

Comment: sourceSets {
 main {
  java {
   srcDir 'src'
   srcDir 'src-gen'
  }
 }
 test {
  java { srcDir 'test' }
 }
}

Comment: Can you try commenting out this line as well: property "sonar.sources", "src". the plugin should pick up main as default sourceset and test as default test sourceset

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jacocoTestReport {
        afterEvaluate {
                sourceDirectories = files(sourceDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [ 'com/path/to/package/that/I/want/to/exclude/are/inside/thisfolder_or_dto/**' ])
                })
                classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [ 'com/path/to/package/that/I/want/to/exclude/are/inside/thisfolder_or_dto/**' ])
                })
        }
}

sonarRunner {
   sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.exclusions", "com/path/to/package/that/I/want/to/exclude/are/inside/thisfolder_or_dto/**"
   }
}

  //Required with Gradle 2.0+ -- 2.0+ -- 2.3
  pmd {
       ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-design" ]
       ignoreFailures = true
  }

   codenarc {
     ignoreFailures = true
     //The following file should exist or build will fail, you can find one online a sample version
     configFile = file("config/codenarc/codenarc.xml")
   }


   checkstyle {
        configFile = new File(rootDir, "config/checkstyle.xml")
        ignoreFailures = true
        //sourceSets = [sourceSets.main, sourceSets.test, sourceSets.integrationTest]

        //Just run checkstyle only on main source code
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   }


   findbugs {
        ignoreFailures = true
        //Just run findbugs only on main source code
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]

        //You can use if statement in groovy to set which toolVersion 2.0.3 or 3.0.1 depending upon JAVA version used in the project
        toolVersion = "3.0.1"
   }
```

Similarly, you can use excludes property within test or test task's jacoco section directly.

```
    def generatedSources = ['com/yahoo/**', 'com/amazon/**']

    test {
         jacoco {
              excludes = generatedSources
         }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
         doFirst {
              classDirectories = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/classes/main/").exclude(generatedSources)
         }
         reports {
              xml.enabled true
         }
    }
```

While publishing to SonarQube (sonar.exclusions=value should be relative from your WORKSPACE i.e. src/java/com/.../...)

Answer (score 0):

sonarRunner plugin is deprecated. Please switch to the official SonarQube plugin: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube